# Как через JavaScript получить данные о пользователе фейсбука?

Tags: javascript, facebook-api, facebooksdk

Пользователь будет вводить свой юзернейм типа "lilith.jan" и по нажатию на кнопку должны заполняться поля имя, фамилия, город, вобщем всё что можно вытянуть с его страницы

Comment: сильно сомневаюсь что так можно сделать "без проблем"(ибо юзер должен сначала быть зареган у вас через тот же фэйсбук). Если он уже зареган, то ajax запрос с токеном поможет вам НО ваш код виден для всех, а я думаю вы наврядли захотите отдать всем свой ключик. Поэтому регистрация на стороне сервака -> отдать общий ключ/токен (не помню точно) на js сторону и уже на стороне js творить, что хочется через ajax.

Comment: Мне как раз при регистрации надо, то есть пользователь ещё никак не может быть зарегистрирован. Надо просто чтоб его данные в форму можно было вставить с фейсбука, чтоб он вручную не вводил

Comment: Так точно никто не разрешит, ибо все данные о человеке (дальше имени кажется) являются приватными и защищены документом о приватных данных самого фэйсбука и еще галочка ставится при регистрации что типа "мы все почитали и согласны". Но давайте посмотрим с другой стороны - зачем вам это надо? По хорошему, если запихнуть на сайт простую кнопочку "зарегаться через facebook" вы сразу же откинете проблемы с безопасностью и получите после регистрации все данные о человеке , которые уже сохраните у себя

Comment: @alexoander, я плсанул за вторую часть. Но вообще клиент-онли данные с фейсбука запросить можно. Другое дело что юзеру все равно придется ткнуть в разрешения приложению.

Comment: @Утка что по сути равнозначно запросу данных от фейсбука(который тоже попросит зарегаться если вы не авторизованы) и доп действий от юзера.

Comment: @alexoander, да, но если данных которые может пригодиться вводить -  достаточно много, это может быть полезно.

Comment: @Утка если данных много и они внутри фэйсбука, то уж точно легче попросить человека зареаться через сам фэйскнигу и потом уже выставить человеку кнопку "заполнить как на фэйсбуке". Хотя это равнозначно =)

Comment: @alexoander, да, здесь я абсолютно с вами согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно вам может пригодится [библиотека Hello.js](https://adodson.com/hello.js/#quick-start).

В любом случае вам придется также завести в фейсбуке (или другой соцсети) приложение, которому юзер будет выдавать доступ к данным при попытке их опросить.

Если Вы не хотите закладываться на стороннюю библиотек, вы можете реализовать это сами с помощью [документации facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login). Для конкретно фейсбука мне делать не приходилось, но крупные соцсети обычно реализуют OAuth 2.0 или что-то очень похожее.